# Change data-url and data-title dynamically via addThis.com

Tags: jquery, ajax, addthis, swiper.js

Site has slider ([Swiper](http://www.idangero.us/swiper/)). After slide end I set new value to data-url and data-title.

When inspect element everything looks OK, yet, when pressing on sharing via mail, for example, I still get default value.

Anyone used addThis.com and changed this data dynamically?

Some code (Which seem to be working in inspect element:

```
var title = $('.swiper-slide-active #videoTitleData').text();
var videoId = $('.swiper-slide-active .singleVideo').attr('id');

$('.swiper-slide-active .addthis_sharing_toolbox').attr('data-url', basicDomain + '?videoId=' + videoId);
$('.swiper-slide-active .addthis_sharing_toolbox').attr('data-title', title);
```

Thx

Answer (score 0):

You can use `addthis.layers.refresh()` to refresh the data in the tools dynamically. However, this would mean you'd also need to be updating the browser's url and the page's `<title>`.

To read more about using the AddThis tools dynamically, check out http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/1692927-using-dashboard-configuration-tools-dynamically